# Using numbers outside the range of unsigned long long?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to use numbers beyond the range of `unsigned long long`. Can anyone help me regarding the use of numbers beyond the range of `unsigned long long`?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need some kind of astronomical numerics library (also called arbitrary-precision arithmetic). GNU's MP Bignum library is nice, if you don't mind the LGPL: http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 3):

Boost has BigNum type implementations as well. That might work for you if you are already using Boost.